# Dynamic calling member method c++

Tags: c++, dynamic, linker, getprocaddress

I know this has been discussed a few times, but my situation is a bit different.

I have a third-party dll exporting some classes. Unfortunately, the header file is not available.
It is still possible to call exported functions. But I cannot get around passing the right 'this' pointer (which is passed in RCX register).

First I use dumpbin /exports to extract the function names (names are changed as the third-party library and function names are confidential).

```
       4873 1308 0018B380 ?GetId@ThirdPartyClass@ThirdPartyNamespace@@QEBAJXZ = ??GetId@ThirdPartyClass@ThirdPartyNamespace@@QEBAJXZ (public: long __cdecl ThirdPartyNamespace::ThirdPartyClass::GetId(void)const )
```

Now, the API allows me to register my callback that receives a pointer to ThirdPartyNamespace::ThirdPartyClass (there is only forward declaration of ThirdPartyClass).

Here how I am trying to call ThirdPartyNamespace::ThirdPartyClass::GetId():

```
long (ThirdPartyNamespace::ThirdPartyClass::*_pFnGetId)() const;
HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle("ThirdPartyDLL.dll");
*(FARPROC*)&_pFnGetId= GetProcAddress(hModule, "?GetId@ThirdPartyClass@ThirdPartyNamespace@@QEBAJXZ");

long id = (ptr->*_pFnGetId)();
```

Everything looks fine (i.e. if I step in - I get indeed inside ThirdPartyClass::GetId method. But the this pointer is not good. While the ptr is good and if in debugger I manually change rcx to the ptr - it works fine. But compiler does not pass ptr for some reason. Here is disassembly:

```
long id = (ptr->*_pFnGetId)();
000000005C882362  movsxd      rax,dword ptr [rdi+30h]  
000000005C882366  test        eax,eax  
000000005C882368  jne         MyClass::MyCallback+223h (05C882373h)
000000005C88236A  movsxd      rcx,dword ptr [rdi+28h]  
000000005C88236E  add         rcx,rsi  
000000005C882371  jmp         MyClass::MyCallback+240h (05C882390h)  
000000005C882373  movsxd      r8,dword ptr [rdi+2Ch]  
000000005C882377  mov         rcx,rax  
000000005C88237A  mov         rax,qword ptr [r8+rsi]  
000000005C88237E  movsxd      rdx,dword ptr [rax+rcx]  
000000005C882382  movsxd      rcx,dword ptr [rdi+28h]  
000000005C882386  lea         rax,[r8+rdx]  
000000005C88238A  add         rcx,rax  
000000005C88238D  add         rcx,rsi  
000000005C882390  call        qword ptr [rdi+20h]  
000000005C882393  mov         ebp,eax
```

Before executing these commands, rsi contains the pointer to the object of ThirdPartyClass (i.e. ptr), but instead of passing it in rcx directly, some arithmetic is performed on it and as a result, this pointer gets completely wrong.

some traces which I don't understand why compiler is doing it as it end up calling non-virtual function ThirdPartyClass::GetId():

```
000000005C88237A  mov         rax,qword ptr [r8+rsi] 
    R8  0000000000000000    
    RSI 000000004C691AA0    // good pointer to ThirdPartyClass object
    RAX 0000000008E87728    // this gets pointer to virtual functions table of ThirdPartyClass
000000005C88237E  movsxd      rdx,dword ptr [rax+rcx] 
    RAX 0000000008E87728    
    RCX FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF    
    RDX FFFFFFFFC0F3C600
000000005C882382  movsxd      rcx,dword ptr [rdi+28h]  
    RCX 0000000000000000    
    RDI 000000005C9BE690    
000000005C882386  lea         rax,[r8+rdx]
    RAX FFFFFFFFC0F3C600    
    RDX FFFFFFFFC0F3C600    
    R8  0000000000000000    
000000005C88238A  add         rcx,rax 
    RAX FFFFFFFFC0F3C600    
    RCX FFFFFFFFC0F3C600    
000000005C88238D  add         rcx,rsi  
    RCX 000000000D5CE0A0    
    RSI 000000004C691AA0    
000000005C882390  call        qword ptr [rdi+20h]
```

In my view, it should be as simple as

```
long id = (ptr->*_pFnGetId)();
mov         rcx,rsi  
call        qword ptr [rdi+20h] 
mov         ebp,eax
```

And if I set rcx equal to rsi before the call qword ptr [rdi+20h] it returns me expected value.

Am I doing something completely wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution, by incident (as I already used similar approach and it worked in slightly different situation.

The solution is to trick the compiler by defining a fake class and calling member method by pointer, but pretending that it is a pointer to the known (to compiler) class.

Perhaps, it does not matter, but I know that ThirdPartyNamespace::ThirdPartyClass has virtual functions, so I declare fake class with virtual function as well.

```
class FakeCall
{
private:
    FakeCall(){}
    virtual ~FakeCall(){}
};
```

The rest as in the initial code except once small thing, instead of calling ptr->*_pFnGetId (where ptr is pointer to unknown, forward declared class ThirdPartyNamespace::ThirdPartyClass), I am pretending I am calling member method in my FakeCall class:

```
    FakeCall * fake = (FakeCall*)ptr;
    long sico = (fake->*_pFnGetId)();
```

Disassembly looks exactly as expected:

```
long sico = (fake->*_pFnGetSico)();
000000005A612096  mov         rcx,rax  
000000005A612099  call        qword ptr [r12+20h]  
000000005A61209E  mov         esi,eax
```

And it works perfectly!

Some observations:

1. The member method pointer, as I thought initially, nothing more than a normal function pointer.
2. Microsoft compiler (at least VS2008) goes crazy if calling member method for not defined class (i.e. only forward declaration of the name).

Comment: Good catch. MSVC uses differently sized pointers to member functions depending on the class, 8 to 24 bytes on a 64 bit platform. See http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link!
It actually has a link with full explanation (still actual since 2015).
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible
This is really mind blowing.
I am lucky that I have single inheritance in the ThirdParty classes in my case.